# Xcode Beta 6 with iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode

When I connect my iPad with iOS 8.0 to xcode beta 6, I can't find the "Use For Development" button that usually appears when selecting your iPad in the "Devices" window. I reset and wiped my iPad so now I need to set it up again for development use. Anyone know how to do this in the new xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some buggy things going on with Xcode betas (no surprise). Try unplugging the iPad, restart Xcode, and plug it back in. I would even go as far as a reboot to your machine.